# How to style the form after clicking the hint in css?

Tags: html, css, forms

I created a login form in HTML, CSS and TypeScript. After typing the login from the keyboard, the input background does not change, but when I choose the login from the browser hint, the background color changes to white. It seems that there are some default browser styles, because it looks a bit different on different browsers. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

[This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yNQx.png)
what the form looks like when, instead of entering the text manually, I choose an option from the browser prompts - white background.

Normally it should be like [around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvqUz.png) - in the picture you can see when I enter the value from the keyboard.

Comment: Please share the code where you are stuck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.